# In TinyMCE is there a feature to allow pasting images when using the backend image load handler which saves uploaded images on the server?

Tags: tinymce

I'm using the image upload script with a backend URL to rename uploaded images stored on the server. It seems to work well with both file uploads and also drag-and-drop.

Without that backend handling you can paste images directly into the editor, but they get saved as base64 with the post in the db itself which is not great for a lot of reasons.

If I use the image upload script as I am now, it seems it blocks the pasting of images directly into the editor. That's safest, I guess, but I was wondering if there was a way of allowing it, but treating the pasted image like a drag-and-drop image, for example, so we could have the convenience of pasting images but still have them saved with unique filenames on the server instead of being embedded as base64 with the rest of the source of the post?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement?  "If I use the image upload script as I am now, it seems it blocks the pasting of images directly into the editor."  What are you trying to paste that is blocked?

Comment: Hi. For example, if I grab a screenshot and want to paste it, like I might do into an email. Or if see an image on the web and I use control-click and select "copy image" and want to paste it (like I might do into a Facebook post).

Comment: That all comes down to what gets placed in the clipboard when you do these copy commands.  If you use a tool to inspect the clipboard what types of content get placed in the clipboard.

Comment: Do there happen to be any examples of the upload script doing this-or-that depending on what's in the clipboard?

Comment: Just wondering if there were any suggestions out there. For example, copying an image from a Word document and being able to paste it into the editor and have it saved on the server.